# Centos 6.7 PHP upgrade to 5.6 from PHP 5.2

Tags: php

Updating PHP to 5.6 from PHP 5.2 on Centos 6.7 cause following errors. Any help?

```
[root@web2 yum.repos.d]# yum upgrade php*

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror

Setting up Upgrade Process

Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile

 * base: centos.mirror.moack.net
 * extras: centos.mirror.moack.net
 * remi: mirror.innosol.asia
 * remi-php56: mirror.innosol.asia
 * updates: centos.mirror.moack.net

Resolving Dependencies

--> Running transaction check

---> Package php.x86_64 0:5.2.17-r4686.mchost will be updated

---> Package php.x86_64 0:5.6.40-9.el6.remi will be an update

---> Package php-cli.x86_64 0:5.2.17-r4686.mchost will be updated

---> Package php-cli.x86_64 0:5.6.40-9.el6.remi will be an update

---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.2.17-r4686.mchost will be updated

--> Processing Dependency: php-pecl-zip(x86-64) for package: php-
common-5.6.40-9.el6.remi.x86_64

---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.6.40-9.el6.remi will be an update

--> Processing Dependency: php-pecl-jsonc(x86-64) for package: php-common-5.6.40-9.el6.remi.x86_64

--> Processing Dependency: php-pecl-zip(x86-64) for package: php-common-5.6.40-9.el6.remi.x86_64

---> Package php-gd.x86_64 0:5.2.17-r4686.mchost will be updated

---> Package php-gd.x86_64 0:5.6.40-9.el6.remi will be an update

--> Processing Dependency: gd-last(x86-64) >= 2.1.1 for package: php-gd-5.6.40-9.el6.remi.x86_64

--> Processing Dependency: libgd.so.3()(64bit) for package: php-gd-5.6.40-9.el6.remi.x86_64

---> Package php-imap.x86_64 0:5.2.17-r4686.mchost will be updated

---> Package php-imap.x86_64 0:5.6.40-9.el6.remi will be an update
---> Package php-mbstring.x86_64 0:5.2.17-r4686.mchost will be updated

---> Package php-mbstring.x86_64 0:5.6.40-9.el6.remi will be an update

---> Package php-mcrypt.x86_64 0:5.2.17-r4686.mchost will be updated

---> Package php-mcrypt.x86_64 0:5.6.40-9.el6.remi will be an update

---> Package php-mssql.x86_64 0:5.2.17-r4686.mchost will be updated

---> Package php-mssql.x86_64 0:5.6.40-9.el6.remi will be an update

---> Package php-mysql.x86_64 0:5.2.17-r4686.mchost will be obsoleted

---> Package php-mysqlnd.x86_64 0:5.6.40-9.el6.remi will be obsoleting

---> Package php-pdo.x86_64 0:5.2.17-r4686.mchost will be updated

---> Package php-pdo.x86_64 0:5.6.40-9.el6.remi will be an update

---> Package php-soap.x86_64 0:5.2.17-r4686.mchost will be updated

---> Package php-soap.x86_64 0:5.6.40-9.el6.remi will be an update

---> Package php-tidy.x86_64 0:5.2.17-r4686.mchost will be updated

---> Package php-tidy.x86_64 0:5.6.40-9.el6.remi will be an update

---> Package php-xml.x86_64 0:5.2.17-r4686.mchost will be updated

---> Package php-xml.x86_64 0:5.6.40-9.el6.remi will be an update

--> Running transaction check

---> Package gd-last.x86_64 0:2.2.5-5.el6.remi will be installed

--> Processing Dependency: libfontconfig.so.1()(64bit) for package: gd-last-2.2.5-5.el6.remi.x86_64

--> Processing Dependency: libtiff.so.3()(64bit) for package: gd-last-2.2.5-5.el6.remi.x86_64

--> Processing Dependency: libwebp.so.5()(64bit) for package: gd-last-2.2.5-5.el6.remi.x86_64

---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.2.17-r4686.mchost will be updated

--> Processing Dependency: php-pecl-zip(x86-64) for package: php-common-5.6.40-9.el6.remi.x86_64

---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.6.40-9.el6.remi will be an update

--> Processing Dependency: php-pecl-zip(x86-64) for package: php-common-5.6.40-9.el6.remi.x86_64

---> Package php-pecl-jsonc.x86_64 0:1.3.10-2.el6.remi.5.6 will be installed

--> Running transaction check

---> Package fontconfig.x86_64 0:2.8.0-5.el6 will be installed

---> Package gd-last.x86_64 0:2.2.5-5.el6.remi will be installed

--> Processing Dependency: libwebp.so.5()(64bit) for package: gd-last-2.2.5-5.el6.remi.x86_64

---> Package libtiff.x86_64 0:3.9.4-21.el6_8 will be installed

---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.2.17-r4686.mchost will be updated

--> Processing Dependency: php-pecl-zip(x86-64) for package: php-common-5.6.40-9.el6.remi.x86_64

---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.6.40-9.el6.remi will be an update

--> Processing Dependency: php-pecl-zip(x86-64) for package: php-common-5.6.40-9.el6.remi.x86_64

--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Error: Package: php-common-5.6.40-9.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)

           Requires: php-pecl-zip(x86-64)

           Removing: php-common-5.2.17-r4686.mchost.x86_64 (installed)

               php-pecl-zip(x86-64) = 1.8.11

           Updated By: php-common-5.6.40-9.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)

               Not found

Error: Package: gd-last-2.2.5-5.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)

           Requires: libwebp.so.5()(64bit)

 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem

 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: Is there any good reason to use such an old PHP version?

Answer (score 0):

1/ first remove everything from *mchost* repository

2/ notice than PHP 5.6 have reach its [end of life](https://www.php.net/eol.php) in December 2018, and despite packages in "remi" repository have security fixes, upgrade to a maintained version is highly recommended.

3/ update your distribution first, as 6.7 is really old, current is **6.10**. You can also consider a fresh installation on CentOS 7.6.

4/ follow the [Wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/) instructions (at least "remi-safe" repository, used for common dependencies, is missing)

Comment: Unfortunately I have to stick with PHP 5.6 cause it is a requirement to run another software.